# Error "Element with id .. already registered" and no SQL connections in the list of VSCode plugin SQLTools

Tags: mysql, vscode-extensions, sqltools

I started learning SQL in VSCode via the SQLTools plugin. I tried to connect to MySQL database `sakila` via the "Add New Connection" button of the SQLTools plugin. On the first 2 tries, I pushed the "Save Connection" button before the connection was OK (even the database was not set up properly then). I expected the connections (even if they are broken) to appear in the connections list (near the "Add Connection" button), but nothing appeared there. On the third time, I created a working connection. Unfortunately, after saving it, it did not appear in the list as well. Now an annoying pop-up with the error "Element with id ... is already registered" (see exact message print-screen below) keeps appearing constantly.
[image: pop-up with error]

1. Where are these elements (mentioned in the error message) registered in (in which file, etc.)? They are not present in VSCode's `settings.json`. Is there some other place?
2. How to get rid of the pop-up with the error message?
3. Why did the correct connection not present in the list of connections even if I can run queries via it (find the print screen below)? How to fix this? In this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/C0y35FpiLRA?t=555) the connections appeared in the list automatically.

[image: print-screen of VSCode window with connection to SQL database]

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion in [this comment](https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/668#issuecomment-993403972) solved the issue.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
→
[image]
→
and then delete the broken connections.